# Checking if input is not disabled with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to send an ajax request only if a input is not disabled. So does not have `disabled="disabled"` property.

Here is the jquery code:

```
if ($('#field_22Travel').not(':disabled')) {
        //send ajax request
        sendAjaxPrefs(catTag, remTag, unsubscribeTag, subscribeFlag);
    }
```

Here is the html input:

```
<input id="field_22Travel" class="check-box" name="field_22Travel" value="Travel" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox">
```

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing just not sure what.
Cheers

Comment: you are using the wrong id, it should be '#field_22Camping' not '#field_22Travel'

Comment: `'field_22Travel'` is not `field_22Camping`

Comment: you are using the wrong method, [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) excludes elements matching the selector from the set contained in the jQuery object. You want to use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and negate the return: `!$().is(':disabled')`

Comment: Sorry gave yall the wrong html input, I'm using multiple inputs. My bad :/ I have updated the question. I know im using right ids etc because the code runs and sends the ajax request. I just want to prevent it from happening if it has the disabled property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with the [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method.

```js
if (!$('#field_22Travel').is('[disabled=disabled]')) {
        alert("hello")
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn button" id="field_22Travel" disabled="disabled"></button>
```

Comment: OP wants to send the request if the input *isn't* disabled. This is backwards.

Comment: You are right, I need to add "!" before the "$('#...')"

Comment: You are also using the wrong link for `is()` reference, the appropriate link is http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: @hansTheFranz this done the trick. Will have to remember the is function for the future, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `prop()` which simply returns a Boolean, something like this:

```js
if (!$('#field_22Travel').prop('disabled')) {
    //send ajax request
    sendAjaxPrefs(catTag, remTag, unsubscribeTag, subscribeFlag);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn button" id="field_22Travel" disabled="disabled"></button>
```